# Adding logic around an arbitrary lambda in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I have several lambdas that do various things.  The number of arguments the lambdas have and the return type is different.

I would like to wrap each one of those lambdas with the same logic.   For example:

```
private inline fun <T:__SOME_MAGIC_HERE__> keepMDC(block: T): T {
    val contextMap = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
    return __ANOTHER_MAGIC_SYNTAX__ {
        val old = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
        MDC.setContextMap(contextMap)
        block.invoke(*args)
        MDC.setContextMap(old)
    }
}
```

This function would ideally be used this way:

```
o.doSomething(keepMDC {
   logger.info("In doSomething callback")
})

o.doSomethingElse(keepMDC { x, y ->
   logger.info("In doSomethingElse with arguments $x and $y")
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the `args` bit. If `block` could receive params then where do they originate from? How `keepMDC()` would know what to pass to `block`? In your example `args` is just unresolved.

Comment: @broot I guess that's the whole question of the OP. The goal is to return a function that accepts the same arguments as the `block`, and pass them on inside the body of `keepMDC`

Comment: Ahh, so `doSomething()` receives parameterless lambda and `doSomethingElse()` receives a lambda with params `x` and `y` - thanks, got it.

Comment: That's how I understood the question, yes

Comment: That right broot/Joffrey. Thanks.  I don't even see any (straight-forward) reflective approach :-(

Comment: To put it another way, it's like the AOP pattern of adding advice around a lambda that depends on the current thread context.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a fully generic way of achieving this, but if you want create a new function based on another function just with some arbitrary logic around, you can do so simply by declaring higher-order functions for different function signatures.

```kotlin
fun <R> wrapping(block: () -> R): () -> R = { wrapped { block() } }
fun <A, R> wrapping(block: (A) -> R): (A) -> R = { a: A -> wrapped { block(a) } }
fun <A, B, R> wrapping(block: (A, B) -> R): (A, B) -> R = { a: A, b: B -> wrapped { block(a, b) } }
fun <A, B, C, R> wrapping(block: (A, B, C) -> R): (A, B, C) -> R = { a: A, b: B, c: C -> wrapped { block(a, b, c) } }

private fun <R> wrapped(block: () -> R): R {
    println("before!")

    val result = block()

    println("after!")

    return result
}
```

Usage examples for this can be found below.

However, if you're in control of the functions and don't want to have both a version with and without the wrapping logic, it most likely is easiest to simply wrap the implementation of your lambdas itself, e.g.:

```kotlin
fun <R> surroundWithLogs(block: () -> R): R {
    println("Before block.")
    val result = block()
    println("After block.")
    return result
}

// > Replace something like this
//fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int =
//    x + y
// > with something like this
fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int = surroundWithLogs {
    x + y
}
```

As your in the same scope, there is no need to pass the parameters through the lambdas, because you can access them in your original, most inner lambda directly.

---

**usage examples**

```
fun three(): Int {
    println("three!")
    return 3
}

fun increase(x: Int): Int {
    println("increase $x!")
    return x + 1
}

fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    println("add $x and $y!")
    return x + y
}

fun foo(x: Int, y: Long, z: Float): String {
    println("$x, ${y}L and ${z}f!")
    return "$x - $y - $z"
}

val wrappedThree = wrapping(::three)
val wrappedIncrease = wrapping(::increase)
val wrappedAdd = wrapping(::add)
val wrappedFoo = wrapping(:foo)

fun main() {
    println(wrappedThree())
    // before!
    // three!
    // after!
    // 3

    println(wrappedIncrease(65))
    // before!
    // increase 65!
    // after!
    // 66

    println(wrappedAdd(3, 4))
    // before!
    // add 3 and 4!
    // after!
    // 7

    println(wrappedFoo(3, 4L, 5f))
    // before!
    // 3, 4L and 5f!
    // after!
    // 3 - 4 - 5.0
}
```

This does not only work with function references, but with lambda as well, e.g:

```kotlin
val wrappedMinOfLambda = wrapping { x: Int, y: Int ->
    println("lambda with $x and $y!")
    minOf(x, y)
}

fun main() {
    println(wrappedMinOfLambda(5, 9))
    // before!
    // lambda with 5 and 9!
    // after!
    // 5
}
```